# How add in the view one method using entities

Tags: entities

I am studying the framework entities and need to add a method in the @view.

This is My code:

```
 

    @Views({
        @View(
         name="CreatClient",
         title="Cliente",
         members="#Codigo;#nome;#Telefone;#Endereco",
         rows=10)
    });
```

Comment: What's the issue here?  Would you please edit to clarify a specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the method name after of endereco in members... 
;methodname()
And make the method in the class